# HTML/CSS: Relative/Absolute Positioning

Tags: html, css

How do I lay an image (such as a circle) over a different image so that it always stays in the right place, regardless of image or browser resizing? Is there a way I can do this with divs?

**Update: Thank you for your help. I have attached some images of relevant html and css to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I'm hoping to get the circles to surround one person's face, even though the image itself resizes with the browser. Thanks!

[Webpage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvwBR.png) [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1cLu.png) [CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8via.png)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't really the place to be asking a question like this. StackOverflow is for solving issues with code. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and Google around a bit to find out more about your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One way I would recommend would be to use position:relative on your circle image, add it after the image you want in on top of, and set the left value to -outerWidth of 1st image. You should also put both of these in a span and add css to prevent line break as well

Answer (score 0):

The code below gives examples of circles that remain within their parent square, and can be positioned in proportion to their parent squares. I've created some CSS so that you can add a class to various divs to change their size, etc.

N.B. You cannot apply `.large` or `.small` to the circles, their size is proportional to their parent `div`, although this does not have to be the case.

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.large {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.small {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.center {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.left-center {
  left: 0;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.right-center {
  left: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square small">
  <div class="circle left-center">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="square">
  <div class="circle center">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="square large">
  <div class="circle right-center">
  </div>
</div>
```